# Drop item spigot

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm making a bedwars plugin for my minecraft server, actually i have to coding a generator for drop item every 1 secs, i have no idea how to make that, with internet i have done this code :

```
        while(true) {
            task = Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(Main.plugin, () -> {
                World w =  null;
                for(Player p : Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) {
                    w = p.getWorld();
                }
                String[] pos = Main.blue_spawn.split("\\*");
                Location loc = new Location(w, Double.parseDouble(pos[0]), Double.parseDouble(pos[1]), Double.parseDouble(pos[2]));
                w.dropItemNaturally(loc, new ItemStack(1));
            }, 20, 20);
        }
```

But i don't know how to drop iron ingot, beaucause do new ItemStack(Material.IRON_INGOT) just give me an error

Pls help

Comment: What is the error that you get ?

Comment: Syntax error, i checked it but i don't find how to drop the item i want

Comment: Please edit your question to include the whole error, and the entire code that produces it. "Syntax error" is not specific enough for us to know what's happening just from the `new ItemStack(Material.IRON_INGOT)` bit that you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NOT use `while(true)` loop in minecraft. It will block the thread, which seems to be the main server thread. The scheduler is enough about staying running.

Then, it's not a good idea about the player loop for getting world. If someone is on the nether or something, it will not work. You can use `Bukkit.getServer().getWorlds()[0]` or `Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world")`.

Also, the `new ItemStack(Material.IRON_INGOT)` should work. [Documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/inventory/ItemStack.html) about it.

Finally, the `dropItemNaturally` method is good. You can see doc [here](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/World.html#dropItemNaturally(org.bukkit.Location,org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack))

Comment: It's work, this, a last things, do you know how to make a loop for my fonction without bloking the thread pls

Comment: Which loop ? By default, the scheduler run indefinitly until you didn't stop it (or stop the server)